# Performance penalty for using small data areas?

Tags: assembly, powerpc, sda

I'm looking at IBM's [**Developing PowerPC Embedded Application Binary
(EABI) Compliant Programs**](https://www-01.ibm.com/chips/techlib/techlib.nsf/techdocs/852569B20050FF77852569970071B0D6/$file/eabi_app.pdf), in particular at table 4 on page 7.

[image]

The benchmark results are 88kDhry/sec without using SDA, and only 77kDhry/sec *with* SDA. I would have expected using SDA not only reduce code size but also improve performance because access to variables only needs two instead of three instructions. Can somebody explain the numbers in the table?

What am I missing?

Comment: I would expect it to be faster too. Could be a simple thing like accidental swapping of the values. Since we don't have access to the test program binaries and environment, I can only suggest to try your own tests.

Comment: I find so few runs of a dhrystone (or any benchmark) to be almost useless.  Need to compile with different levels of optimization.  Add or rearrange code (I normally add or remove nops) in the startup code or early in the binary to adjust where the code hits the cache lines, etc.  Use different compilers, the same source code on the same machine on the same day should have a good width on dhrystone performance results, any single number is no better than pulling the number out of thin air and reporting that.  and dhrystones only matter if dhrystone is your primary application.

Comment: Would the downvoter please care to state what is wrong with my question?

Comment: Compile it and diff the assembly code?

Comment: I don't have the IBM High C compiler. (and I don't believe in programming by experimentation :-)